# As I am defining classes in scala, The controls is then not going inside the main function. What to do?

Tags: scala, class, oop, object, controls

```
class User(private var name : String, var age : Int);

object Demo{

def main(args: Array[String]) {

    //var user = new User("Harsh", 24);

    if(true) {
        println("here")
    } else {
        println("In else")
    }

    println("Ok")



}
```

}

This is my scala code and when I comment out the class "User" defined the output is

---

here

### Ok

And when I am using the class, I am not getting any output. 
Any idea what is happening

Answer (score 1):

On JVM everything starts in `main` function and program will together end with `main` function unless there are other non-daemon threads running.

Until you get to threads just assume that if there is no call path from `main` to some code - then this code is never called.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly: when you uncomment the two commented lines, it doesn't compile because there's no `printName` method in `User`. If it doesn't compile, there is nothing to run so no output from running. But you *should* get some output telling you about the compilation error or about an attempt to run a non-existent file.

Comment: @ Alexey I have edited the question. Leave that line. I had function defined earlier for that class

Comment: How exactly are you running your code? You can see it working here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nch4NlVQTierAkuosi5Rkg

Comment: I am running it from the command line                                                                                                                        Using scala classes.scala (This is the file name)